# Изменить символы . , : ; - ! ? на пробелы

Tags: c#

Из textbox'а(1) вводятся данные (любые числа или буквы),если между ними есть знаки препинания (.,:;-!?) они заменяются на пробелы.Сама программа работает,но мне кажется что ее возможно сократить или ускорить.Как можно это сделать?
Вот фрагмент кода:

```
        string[] s = textBox1.Lines;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            if (s[i].Contains("."))
            {
                s[i] = s[i].Replace(".", " ");
            }
            if (s[i].Contains(","))
            {
                s[i] = s[i].Replace(",", " ");
            }
            if (s[i].Contains(":"))
            {
                s[i] = s[i].Replace(":", " ");
            }
            if (s[i].Contains(";"))
            {
                s[i] = s[i].Replace(";", " ");
            }
            if (s[i].Contains("-"))
            {
                s[i] = s[i].Replace("-", " ");
            }
            if (s[i].Contains("!"))
            {
                s[i] = s[i].Replace("!", " ");
            }
            if (s[i].Contains("?"))
            {
                s[i] = s[i].Replace("?", " ");
            }

        }
        textBox2.Lines = s;

    }
```

Comment: `var result = string.Join(string.Empty, "Привет, мир!".Select(x => ".,:;-!?".Contains(x)? ' ' : x));`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ А вывод строки в textBox2?

Comment: А сами подумать? в `result` у вас будет `string`, делайте дальше с этой строкой что хотите, хотите в текст, так и пишите `textBox2.Text = result;` (или какое у него там свойство текста).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"[.|,|:|;|-|!|?]*", "");
```

Comment: какой-то у вас интересный паттерн. может всё-таки `[.,:;\-!?]+`? так-то `|` тоже парсятся.

Answer (score 0):

var res =  Get(new List() { "Изменить символы . , : ; - ! ? на пробелы" });

```
    public List<string> Get(IEnumerable<string> list)
    {
        List<string> ret = new List<string>();
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"[.,:;\-!?]");
        foreach (var f in list) ret.Add(regex.Replace(f ?? "", ""));
        return ret;
    }
```